# HADOOP_CONF_DIR not found error in python pydoop program

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I am using Pydoop to connect to hdfs files system inside the python program. This python program try to read/ write files in hdfs. When I try to execute I am getting error.

The command used to execute :
Command :

```
hadoop jar /usr/share/bigdata/hadoop-1.2.0/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.0.jar -file ./Methratio.py -mapper './Methratio.py  -d /user/hadoop/gnome.fa -r -g  -o hdfs://ai-ole6-main.ole6.com:54311/user/hadoop/bsmapout.txt hdfs://ai-ole6-main.ole6.com:54311/user/hadoop/Example.bam ' -input sampleinput.txt -output outfile
```

The Error :

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201501251859_0001/attempt_201501251859_0001_m_000000_1/work/./Methratio.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sys, time, os, array, optparse,pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop-1.0.0_rc1-py2.7.egg/pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop-1.0.0_rc1-py2.7.egg/pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py", line 92, in init
    pydoop.hadoop_classpath(), _ORIG_CLASSPATH, pydoop.hadoop_conf()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop-1.0.0_rc1-py2.7.egg/pydoop/__init__.py", line 103, in hadoop_classpath
    return _PATH_FINDER.hadoop_classpath(hadoop_home)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop-1.0.0_rc1-py2.7.egg/pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 551, in hadoop_classpath
    jars.extend([self.hadoop_native(), self.hadoop_conf()])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop-1.0.0_rc1-py2.7.egg/pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 493, in hadoop_conf
    PathFinder.__error("hadoop conf dir", "HADOOP_CONF_DIR")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop-1.0.0_rc1-py2.7.egg/pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 385, in __error
    raise ValueError("%s not found, try setting %s" % (what, env_var))
ValueError: hadoop conf dir not found, try setting HADOOP_CONF_DIR
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

The code :

```
with hdfs.open(options.reffile) as hdfsfile:
    for line in hdfsfile.open(options.reffile):
        if line[0] == '>': 
        #some processing
```

Answer (score 3):

HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable must be set to appropriate location i.e. the path to the folder containing files like core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml etc. Generally these files can be found in **hadoop/etc/** folder.
In my case, I installed Hadoop 2.6 from tarball and placed the extracted folder in /usr/local.
I added the following line in **~/.bashrc**
`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop`

 Then just give the command `source ~/.bashrc` from terminal.